# IMPRESIONES DESDE CELULAR, TABLET U OTRO PC

Tags: html, jquery, nodejs

tengo este codigo en el lado cliente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Enviar a Impresora</title>
    <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="enviarAImpresora()">Imprimir</button>

    <script>
        function enviarAImpresora() {
    const textoAImprimir = "¡Hola, mundo!";
    const url = 'http://192.168.18.51:3000/imprimir/restaurante-x';

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        },
        body: textoAImprimir,
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        alert('Impresión exitosa');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error de impresión:', error);
        alert('Error de impresión');
    });
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

en el servidor tengo este codigo

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Middleware para permitir CORS
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.text());

// Configuración dinámica de impresoras
const impresoras = {
    'restaurante-x': 'Nombre de la impresora para restaurante X',
    'restaurante-z': 'Nombre de la impresora para restaurante Z',
    // Agrega más impresoras según sea necesario
};

app.post('/imprimir/:restaurante', (req, res) => {
    const restaurante = req.params.restaurante;
    const data = req.body;

    if (impresoras[restaurante]) {
        const printerName = impresoras[restaurante];

        // Configurar el HTML con los datos
        const htmlContent = `${data}`;
        console.log(htmlContent);
        // Opciones de configuración para html-pdf
        const pdfOptions = {
            format: 'A4',
        };

        // Crear el PDF
        pdf.create(htmlContent, pdfOptions).toStream((err, stream) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`Error al generar el PDF para ${restaurante}:`, err);
                res.status(500).send('Error de impresión');
            } else {
                // Configurar los encabezados CORS en la respuesta HTTP
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
                res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename=${printerName}.pdf`);
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Configura el origen según sea necesario

                // Piped para imprimir directamente
                stream.pipe(res);

                console.log(`Trabajo de impresión enviado para ${restaurante}`);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('Restaurante no encontrado');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor en funcionamiento en http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

me sale impresion exitosa y sale el hola mundo en la consola del servidor, pero no sale en la impresora, la impresora que estoy usando es una post xprinter

agradeceria su ayuda muchachos

estuve intentando con librerias como printer y esa libreria nunca la pude instalar por versionamientos, use node-printer y esta obsoleta ya no funciona, si hago una impresion directa con window.print() si funciona pero la idea es que yo pueda usar en la nube eso y llegue la impresion sin problema asi la use desde un celular o tablet

estoy utilizando node js porque es lo mas cerca que he estado, en si es un proyecto con solo html y jquery, no se puede usar php, pero puedo usar C# si deseo, como tal no es el servidor el que envia a imprimir, pueden haber varios ordenadores 192.168.10.1, 2, 3, etc. y digamos que en el aplicativo puedo decir que imprima a la 192.168.10.3 y luego a la .1,

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_de_impresi%C3%B3n

Comment: Hola yussef, no pero no aplica para mi proyecto, el contexto es como si fuera una plaza de comidas, con varios restaurantes, entonces digamos que yo pido una orden y la orden involucra 2 restaurantes, deben salir dos ordenes por separado por restaurante a cada impresora correspondiente

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas pasarlo a PDF antes de imprimir?

Comment: @JhonatanPeláez Entonces claramente necesitas que el servidor pueda enviar a imprimir, me parece que usas `nodejs` como servidor, yo nunca lo he usado así que no te puedo ayudar. Solo aconsejarte que edites tu pregunta y añadas la etiqueta `nodejs` así atraerás la atención de las personas que se manejan en esa tecnología. Además eliminar de la jQuery que no tiene nada que ver en el asunto

Comment: Hola yussef, pues estoy utilizando node js porque es lo mas cerca que he estado, en si es un proyecto con solo html y jquery, no se puede usar php, pero puedo usar C# si deseo, como tal no es el servidor el que envia a imprimir, pueden haber varios ordenadores 192.168.10.1, 2, 3, etc. y digamos que en el aplicativo puedo decir que imprima a la 192.168.10.3 y luego a la .1,